# HoneyComb activity preview showing 5 activities in one screen

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I would like to open an activity which in turns uses startActivityForResult window and opens, let us assume, 5 activities. So in the UI I would like it to display using the format present in the attached screen shot format.

See the attached honeycomb picture, I would like the 5 square to represent each activity that is linked to the main activity.

Is it possible in HoneyComb? What is the view name that I should be using?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the picture from something else in Honeycomb, or just a concept? You could try grabbing the root views of the activities and stuffing them into a [`Gallery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) but I'd frankly be amazed if that worked without any problems.

Comment: This picture is from the Honeycomb display. Even I was thinking about hte Gallery, but isn't it just for image files?

Comment: It's definitely intended for images, but according to the docs, it works with any old `View`, so it's worth a shot. If it does work, that would be sweet!

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting, let me give it a shot.